# x2go session: window freezes by inactivity

Tags: x2go

Good evening,

currently, I am working on a x2go-session which freezes after a certain amount of time. Only new starting then will help. My home laptop is a Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6 and I am connecting on a linux. My colleagues (probably all linux users) solved the problem by disabling the screensaver (settings and so on...) but for me it is not working.

Does anybody have the same issue? Any idea or solutions? I need to "keep the window" active to keep my calculations going (from the x2go session I connect via ssh to another server; that connection will close if the window freezes)

Thanks in advance,
Elmo

Answer (score 2):

On the server, in /etc/ssh/sshd_config try setting

TCPKeepAlive yes

ClientAliveInterval 30

I tried everything else I could find, screensaver settings, power options settings, etc.  Nothing worked until I did this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me (on Ubuntu 20.04 + XFCE).

Comment: @Pamphile did you find a solution to this? I also have this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 + XFCE.

Comment: @user171780 no...

Answer (score 2):

Disable the screensaver, or ssh into the machine and kill the active screensaver process.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling screensaver on ubuntu 22.04 xfce4 didn't solve the problem.
Removing xfce4-screensaver did:
`sudo apt-get remove xfce4-screensaver`.
I also disabled display power management: Application > Settings > Power Manager > Display > Display power management

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me as it is stated earlier:

On the server, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` try setting (activate them):

```
TCPKeepAlive yes ClientAliveInterval 30
```

- My client system: ***Mac os Ventura***
- The server that I was connecting: ***Ubuntu 20, XFCE***

Also, it'd be harmless to deactivate the screen saver:

`sudo apt-get remove xfce4-screensaver`

Comment: the readability would be improved by use code formatting ` ` `